# How to Setup Guest VS Registered User Funnel in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How should I setup a guest and a registered user checkout conversion funnel?

I need to setup a guest and a registered user funnel to track conversions separately. Specifically, we need to look at goal completions (conversions), cart abandonment, bounce, exit, as we A/B different page views (changing UI on middle pages).

> Problem:
>
> 1) The regex does not seem to match the pages in the funnel, and so it is showing zero completed sessions (although a conversion of 0.8%)

The typical flow goes: Cart > Login > Shipping > Review > Complete, but the query string doesn't show up until the shipping page, so I've started the funnel there. If I understand correctly, the funnel only looks at the required first page and the last step, so I've only added the query string parameter there.

I've tried these two regular expressions.

```
 Regular Expression: ^\/complete\?guest=.*$
 Regular Expression: /complete\?guest=1
```

They return conversion results, but the funnel shows no completed sessions. I understand the conversions ignore the funnel and just looks at the last page. So, that means my funnel URLs are wrong or my regular expression isn't doing what I hope.

**Guest Destination Goal**

```
 Regular Expression: /complete\?guest=1

 Step 1: /shipping?guest=1 (required)
 Step 2: /review
 Step 3: /complete?guest=1
```

**Registered User Destination Goal**

```
 Regular Expression: /complete

 Step 1: /shipping (REQUIRED)
 Step 2: /review
 Step 3: /complete
```

Comment: maybe /complete$

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your RegEx of `/complete\?guest=1` will be working fine.

One of the most common issues for data issues on these pages if switching on your e-commerce on the view you are using. This one crops up when you are using multiple views to test your e-commerce settings and forget to put it on the one you usually use.

To do this, simply go into your account Analytics >> Property >> View >> eCommerce >> Toggle switch “ON”.